# Prepared statement not working in Admin Panel

Tags: php, mysqli

I have converted simple statements in a PHP project to prepared statements at several places and they seem to work just fine except in the Admin Panel which is creating a lot of problem for me. The code used in the admin panel is as under.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $result=$mysqli->prepare("select * from admin where username=? and password=?");
        $result->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
        $result->execute();

        $count=$result->num_rows;
        if($count>0)
        {
            $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['aid']=$row['aid'];
            header("location:home.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Check your username and password";
        }

    }
```

I would like to mention that before using prepared statements, the project was working fine. The database fields i.e `username` and `password` are `varchar`. I have a connection to the `config file` too which is working as the project was functional before I made any changes.

Comment: what exactly that makes your code not working?

Comment: @david I am not able to log-in, the else block of the code is running.

Comment: probably your config is not right or the database is not right. try dump the username and password

Comment: @david I just told that the config file and database are the same and the code was functional till the point I used prepared statements. Also, checked, they are working just fine.

Comment: Are you storing passwords without encryption? (Not that it should cause the problem, but something that should be of concern)

Comment: @NigelRen For the time being yes. But I would convert the passwords using md5 encryption before finalizing things. Any idea how prepared statements will work in my case?

Comment: Check that the user name and password are getting there OK (add them to the message if needed).  There is also no error reporting, so perhaps adding some would help in case something is failing silently.

Comment: Username and password is being fetched correctly. There is something lacking in the code because `$count` is giving me 0 which is not correct.

Comment: This is one of those times where PDO is **much** easier than MySQLi. Storing / fetching results of `SELECT` queries _"just works ™"_. Also, MD5 hashing is a bad idea for passwords. See http://php.net/manual/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `$result->store_result()` before checking the affected number of rows. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).

Alternatively, just fetch the result - if there is no result, `fetch_assoc()` will return NULL:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from admin where username=? and password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt_result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($stmt_result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['aid']=$row['aid'];
        header("location:home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Check your username and password";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to get `$count` but how to go about getting values from `fetch_assoc`?

Comment: I edited my answer to just check the response of `fetch_assoc()` directly. This is better.

Comment: I am getting an error. `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() `.

Comment: Right. Normally you would [bind the result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) but I have edited my response to use `fetch_assoc` properly now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working now. Can you plz give me links to some resources for learning `prepared statements`.

Comment: On [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) you can see an example with `get_result()` and `fetch_assoc()` and also with `bind_result()`. The official documentation, together with the user contributed notes at the bottom, is what works best for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last question, what do you prefer PDO or prepared statements?

Comment: Hehe, I could answer that... But you shouldn't care what some random guy on the internet prefers to use. You need to find out what *you* prefer to use. :) But for now, keep learning prepared statements. Once you've got the grip of it, you could try PDO and see how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks again! You've been a great help.